# Need to go back to a specific commit

Tags: git

I'm having trouble understanding how to go back to previous commit. Say I have a commit that's 5 commits back or so. I want to remove all the work since then and start from that commit. Do I need to do reset or revert?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 1):

Depends.

If you pushed it, better revert them on by one.

If you didn't, just `git reset --hard HEAD~5`.

Comment: After git reset --hard HEAD~5 what commands do I need? Do I need to add files and commit and push? Or pull?

Comment: If you issued this command, this mean you've never pushed your repository. So no further step is required, enjoy your reseted repo.

Comment: If I reset with `git reset --hard HEAD~5` and then make some changes and try to push I get `Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind`, how do I resolve this?